# Cannot add superscripts to facet label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot make the facet wrap for Rsquared have a 2 superscript. I know there are many questions about this but I have tried the suggestions and cannot make it work. Here is what I have:

```
my_labeller <- as_labeller(c( MAE = "MAE", RMSE = "RMSE", R2= "*R^2*",
                       default = label_parsed))
```

And then:

```
error %>% mutate(across(Metric, factor, levels=c("MAE" , "RMSE" , "R2"), labels = 
c("MAE" , "RMSE" , "R^2"))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Buffer, y=Value, group=Model))+
geom_line(aes(color=Model)) +
geom_point(aes(color=Model)) +
theme_bw() +
labs(y = "Value", x = bquote('Buffer radius (m)')) +
facet_wrap(~ Metric, nrow = 3, scales = "free_y", labeller=my_labeller)
```

But the graph still has R^2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks nearly correct to me, but the "*" characters are unnecessary. In fact when I try to use "*", R throws an error.

Your use of `factor` to change the label names is also unnecessary, and will cause the labeler to miss the label for "R2" entirely, since you have re-labeled it "R^2".

Syntax for setting mathematical expressions in facet labels has changed between versions of ggplot, so a lot of the advice out there is out of date. The following works with ggplot 3.3.5. Construct a labeller using `as_labeller` and specify `default = label_parsed`.

In this example, I am modifying the "cyl" column of the "mtcars" data set to closely match your situation (the `mutate` line). Note that the names of the labeller vector must match the labels you define in `factor`. The *values* of the labeller can be anything.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_labeller = as_labeller(
  c(
    MAE = 'MAE', 
    RMSE = 'RMSE', 
    `R^2` = 'R^2'
    ), 
  default = label_parsed
)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 6, 8), labels = c('MAE', 'RMSE', 'R^2'))) %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = carb, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~cyl, labeller = my_labeller)
```

[image]

Comment: The reason why I use factor is to change the order of the facets so that R2 is the last facet so I need to keep that. When I remove the asterisks like in your great example it still does not make the 2 a superscript...

Comment: I've edited my answer to more closely match your situation.